# Application crash with pointer, header file and struct array

Tags: c, arrays, eclipse, pointers, struct

I've created a project in C with 3 files, main.c where I write a main:

**main.c**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct{
    char nome[29];
    char cognome[28];
    int et;
}s_persona;

int main(){
    s_persona personaX[5];

    caricamento(&personaX[5]);

    int i;

    for(i=0;i<=5;i++){
        printf("Nome: %s\t Cognome: %s\t Eta': %d\n", personaX[i].nome, personaX[i].cognome, personaX[i].et);
    }

    system("pause");
}
```

then a **header file** with a prototype (struct.h):

```
#ifndef STRUCT_H_
#define STRUCT_H_

void caricamento(s_pers perso[5])

#endif /* STRUCT_H_ */
```

and another source file with a function (struct.c):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct{
    char nome[29];
    char cognome[28];
    int et;
}s_pers;

void caricamento(s_pers* perso[5]){
    int k;

    for(k=0;k<=5;k++){
        printf("Inserisci nome dello studente: ");
        scanf("%s", perso[k]->nome);

        printf("Inserisci cognome dello studente: ");
        scanf("%s", perso[k]->cognome);

        printf("Inserisci l'eta' dello studente: ");
        scanf("%d", &perso[k]->et);
    }
}
```

Ok, there are all file that I used. Eclipse build project, without errors, but, whene I insert first string, the application stops working and crash. 
I try create another application be like this, but without use a struct array, and it's working perfectly... 
How I resolve this?

Thanks!!

Comment: `caricamento(&personaX[5]);` should be `caricamento(personaX);` or `caricamento(&personaX[0]);` to match the prototype in the .h file, but not in .c file.

Comment: Also your `k` in `for()` loop should be strictly < tha 5 so: `for(k=0;k<5;k++)`

Comment: "without errors" - but were there warnings?

Comment: There is no `#include "struct.h"` at the top of your main.

Comment: `s_persona personaX[5]` is an array of 5 `s_persona` structs. `s_pers* perso[5]` is an array of 5 **pointers** to `s_pers` structs. `&personaX[5]` is a pointer to the memory address right after the array. Arrays indexes start with `0` in C, and end at `n-1`, so `personaX[5]` and `k <= 5` are both wrong. You have two structs with same contents but different name, remove one of them.

Comment: Why do you have two different typedefs (`s_pers`, and `s_persona`) for the same data structure?

Comment: Guys, I've follow all your comments, but continue at doesn't working...

Comment: place the struct definition + typedef in the header file, so both source files see the same definition.

Comment: in C, the index into an array has the range 0,,,(number of elements in array -1)   so any index == number of elements in array is actually one past the end of the array.

Comment: the posted code contains several 'magic' numbers.  'magic' numbers are numbers with no basis.  I.E.  5, 28, 29.  'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, etc. Suggest using an `enum` statement or `#define` statements to give those 'magic' numbers meaningful names, then use those meaningful names throughout the code

Answer (score 0):

Your header is not used at all. It would be best to define the structure in the header and include the header in your source files (as mentioned in the comments above).

```
#ifndef STRUCT_H_
#define STRUCT_H_

typedef struct{
    char nome[29];
    char cognome[28];
    int et;
} s_pers;

void caricamento(s_pers *perso)

#endif /* STRUCT_H_ */
```

Then in your main.c `include` the header and as also mentioned in the comments pass `personaX`. Otherwise you would pass the address of the sixth element, that does not even exist! Since arrays start at 0 you may only iterate until `k < 5`.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <struct.h>    /* include your header! */

/* 
  Structure already defined in header, 
  no need to define it here! 
 */

int main(){
    s_pers personaX[5];

    caricamento(personaX);

    int i;
    for(i=0;i<5;i++){
        printf("Nome: %s\t Cognome: %s\t Eta': %d\n", 
            personaX[i].nome, personaX[i].cognome, personaX[i].et);
    }

    system("pause");
}
```

In your struct.c make sure to include your header and make sure your function matches the function declaration in your header file! Again make sure to stop at 5, so use `k < 5`.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <struct.h>    /* include your header! */

void caricamento(s_pers* perso){
    int k;

    for(k=0;k<5;k++){
        printf("Inserisci nome dello studente: ");
        scanf("%s", perso[k].nome);

        printf("Inserisci cognome dello studente: ");
        scanf("%s", perso[k].cognome);

        printf("Inserisci l'eta' dello studente: ");
        scanf("%d", &perso[k].et);
    }
}
```